# Installing PySide on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Trying to get my feet wet with PySide development but having trouble
getting setup. I tried installing the [binaries 1.0.4-r1 and 1.0.5](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX) but
both of those produced the following message on import PySide

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/__init__.py", line 2,
 in <module>
 import private
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/private.py", line 2,
 in <module>
 from QtCore import __moduleShutdown

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/
QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
Reason: image not found
```

Then I tried doing the install from the [gitorious build scripts](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/buildscripts). Using
sudo ./dependencies.osx.sh. After that completed I now get the
following error on import PySide.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/__init__.py", line 2,
in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PySide/private.py", line 2,
in <module>
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

Any advice is appreciated. I'm using QtCreator 2.2.1 and Qt SDK
1.1.2 / Qt Library 4.7.3. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a similar situation on OSX 10.6.8 installing the most recent versions of PySide and QT.

Comment: same thing when installing with macports...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install latest version MacPorts and python 2.7 first and set python2.7 as default python version:

```
sudo port install python27
port select --list python
sudo port select --set python python27
```

then re-install PySide again:

```
sudo port install py27-pyside
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered exactly the same problem:

`Library not loaded: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore`

You need to find installed QT libraries and make them visible to the dynamic linker.

My `Qt*.framework` folders live in `/usr/local/lib` (Qt is installed with Homebrew package manager). So, I added

`export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`

to `~/.bash_profile` and restarted the console.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem by using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install pyside.

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall pyside
$ brew install pyside
```