# pyside import error on mac osx

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to use [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySideDocumentation) so I did a `brew install pyside pyside-tools`. However, I get the following error:

```
>>> from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so, 2): Library not loaded: QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtGui.so
  Reason: image not found
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970319/installing-pyside-on-osx-10-6-8) SO question says to install python 27 and then reinstall pyside but I'm using the native python on mac osx 10.8 and it is already 2.7.2.

The [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/15450) recipe for PySide seems to indicate that this should have been fixed but I'm still getting the errors. I made sure libpng is installed as well.

Looking at the path, I know that the QtGui.so file is there. Since I'm new to Python, PySide, and Qt, it is hard for me to Google and further troubleshoot.

If anyone knows why and can provide directions, I will be very grateful. It can involve uninstalling a bunch of stuff and reinstalling. Please give detailed instructions. I did uninstall and try to reinstall and got the same result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error, and I'm using Python installed via Homebrew. I found two PySide libraries in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ . Moving them out of the way, and re-building/installing PySide through Homebrew worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the import you gave - I am using same system environment. It worked fine. try: brew update and re-install.

Comment: specify please, install what?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error when running `ipython qtconsole` which will import PySide to provide a Qt console.

Finally I thought there might be something wrong after PySide's installation. So I run `pyside_postinstall.py -install` manually which should be automatically run after PySide is installed, and this fixed my problem. Hopes working for your too!